# How does one get debugging information out of a cfWindow

Tags: java, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

We decided to use cfWindows for our modal dialogs.  This is something that cannot be changed, so answers and comments of "use another framework" will not resolve the issue.

While we have debugging turned on for our IP addresses, and the debugging information shows up just fine on normal pages, nothing appears in cfWindows.  Today I went about trying to recreate the debugging information and manually write it out to the window HTML.  I began by using the following code in onRequestEnd, which worked fine on pages called normally:

```
<cfset tempFactory = createObject("java", "coldfusion.server.ServiceFactory")>
<cfset tempCfdebugger = tempFactory.getDebuggingService()>
<cfset qEvents = tempCfdebugger.getDebugger().getData()>
```

After taking the time to format the output as desired, I finally tried this on a cfWindow.  However, I received the following error on the third line of code:

```
Detail  Its possible that a method called on a Java object created by CreateObject returned null.
ErrNumber   0
Message     Value must be initialized before use.
```

This implies that it's not just that CF is set not to display debugging information in cfWindows, but that the Java elements that supply the debugging information don't work the same in the case of cfWindows.  I understand very little about the underlying Java, and the code I posted was taken from a CF blog some time ago, so I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this issue.

Is it possible to get debugging information for pages called within a cfWindow?  If so, how?

**EDIT**

To follow up on a suggestion in the comments, I have tried opening the CFWindow templates in their own browser window.  Debugging information appears as normal.  I then tried CFDumping the results of each of the three lines listed above.  The first two work.  The "tempCfdebugger" variable does contain a function called "getDebugger()".  The problem seems to be when that function is called within a CFWindow.  The server must be somehow interpreting CFWindow requests differently.

Is there a different way to get this debugging information other than connecting to the ServiceFactory?

Comment: Can't you just open the URL that's being loaded into CFWINDOW into a new tab on it's own?

Comment: Not exactly.  There are a lot of variables passed in and out of the windows, and many windows rely on interaction with the caller.  There are other barriers as well.  But thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Then you may want to rethink your workflow :D

Comment: It's interesting that you seem to *know* `cfwindow` is a poor approach to addressing your needs, but you still went ahead and used it. I wonder what the decision-maker was thinking here. Seriously.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comment.  I don't know it was a bad choice.  I know that decisions such as this are predicated upon many complicated variables too numerous to go into for a simple question, including available research time and speed of implementation.  I DO know that any time I bring up built-in CF functions I get a swath of responders who make assumptions about those variables and tell me that I'm wrong and that I must justify a year long project to management to switch to JQuery (or similar), which is not practical in the real world.  I was trying to head off this discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to award the bounty to Scott, as he correctly suggested the _cf_nodebug url variable which resolved the original issue.  However, I wanted to post a more complete answer here.

Scott was correct that we could get full debugging information in a cfWindow by appending _cf_nodebug=true to the url when making the call (though I'm not clear on the logic given the name of the variable).  This solved the problem as stated in the original question and was easy to add to our cf_window custom tag; thank you so much Scott.  However, I poorly worded the question as we were actually trying to get debugging information from all cfWindow interactions, including the AJAX requests.  This ended up being a two stage fix, with _cf_nodebug taking care of stage one.

While we now have the ability to get debug information from the initial load of the cfWindow, we also needed to modify the cfc to report details on the queries.  I could find no url variable that would allow us to access the serviceFactory from a cfc, but given that it was a cfc, and essentially just a dense collection of queries, I was able to add the following function to the component to reproduce some of the desired functionality:

```
    <cffunction name="debugFunc" access="private" output="yes">
        <cfparam name="session.debugEnabled" default="false">
        <cfif session.debugEnabled>
            <cfoutput>
                <cfsavecontent variable="debugDetails">
                    Recordcount: #Request.getDataQueryResult.recordcount#<br>
                    Execution Time: #Request.getDataQueryResult.ExecutionTime#ms<br>
                    <cfif isDefined('Request.getDataQueryResult.sqlparameters')>
                        Params: #Request.getDataQueryResult.sqlparameters#<br>
                    </cfif>
                    <br>
                    #Request.getDataQueryResult.sql#
                </cfsavecontent>

                <script>
                    parent.cfWindowDebugDivAdd("cfWindow: #url.method#", "#ReplaceList(debugDetails, "#Chr(10)#,#Chr(13)#,""", " ")#");
                </script>
            </cfoutput>
        </cfif>
    </cffunction>
```

I then did a search and replace in the cfc to modify the beginning and end of each of our 100 or so cfQuery tags:

```
        <cfquery result="Request.getDataQueryResult" ...>
            ...
        </cfquery>
        <cfset debugFunc()>
```

This stores the query information in a struct in the Request scope, then calls the debug function above to write some JS to pass that back to the parent page.  All you need then is a function on the parent page to take the debug information and dump it into a div, span, or browser console.  In case it helps anyone else, here is the code I used for my testing:

```
    <div id="cfWindowDebugDiv" style="width:1000px; height:300px; overflow:auto; text-align:left;"></div>

    <script>
        function cfWindowDebugDivAdd(heading, details) {
            $("#cfWindowDebugDiv").append("<b><u>" + heading + "</u></b><br>");
            $("#cfWindowDebugDiv").append(details + "<br><br><br><br>");
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Nicholas.  This is a nice answer that demonstrates how you solved the problem.  This note was from the CF Docs on cfajaxproxy: "The proxy passes a _CF_NODEBUG Boolean argument to called CFC functions. ColdFusion checks this value, and when it is true, does not append to the response any debugging information that it normally would send. This behavior ensures that the JSON responses to AJAX requests do not include any non-JSON (i.e., debug information) text."

Answer (score 2):

Cfwindow and other AJAX features are more difficult to debug (Not just ColdFusion AJAX).  For cfwindow, you could add this to the URL:

?cfdebug

A more complete explanation of how/what this does is here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec10e40-8000.html

I would also recommend getting to know how to use Firebug.  It does take some time to learn but it will be useful for other projects (standard jQuery/AJAX).  It is well worth the time to learn.

You are going to get comments regarding other platforms/strategies for this kind of development.  I have been burned by using the internal Adobe features; cfform, cfinput, etc.  I've found that it is painful to learn jQuery, but it beats the pain that Adobe dished out to me when I upgraded to new versions of ColdFusion.  I have also run into some browser compatibility problems with cfwindow.

**UPDATE:**
I think that by adding code to the OnRequestEnd() that you are breaking the normal operations of CF AJAX calls.  Read my comment to the Ben Forta blog regarding trouble that I was having (search for jibben after opening this link).

http://forta.com/blog/index.cfm/2007/6/4/ColdFusion-Ajax-Tutorial-4-Partial-Page-Updates

**SHORT VERSION:** Adding content output using OnRequestEnd() will break CF AJAX calls because many of them expect JSON or other formatted data.  Adding a simple "hello<br>" to this functions will append it to the data stream and will break the expected formatting.

I would recommend adding your debugging dumps to the page that cfwindow is calling in the source attribute.

**ADDITIONAL NOTE:** I'm adding this because it may help.  CF has another URL/Query String variable called _cf_nodebug.  When false, it turns on debugging output.

Comment: I apologize for the delay in responding.  We did look at cfdebug, but have had trouble getting it to work.  In any case, I thought this only looked at the ajax request and not any of the CF debugging information.  Is that not the case?

Comment: Did you remove your comment regarding _cf_nodebug?  That actually got me on the right path...

Comment: Yes, I did, I wasn't sure if it would help in this instance.  Glad that you saw it before it was deleted.

Comment: So am I; it was they key to the whole thing!  :)

Comment: I added some info about it as an additional note.  When I first started using the CF AJAX calls in CF8, it seemed really difficult to test/debug those features.  Gradually I found these two.  I think that the _cf_nodebug variable can show up in the AJAX debugging window and that's where I discovered that one.